# Click every link on multiple webpages

Tags: command-line, bash, wget

In our project we have pages like `http://123.4.5.6/3/4`; inside there are a few pages. I need to access the URLs and to click on every link within them to download some files (in an automated way).

How do I achieve such a thing?

Comment: Do you need to actually click or do you just want to download the files?

Comment: Also post a sample of one page, and specify whether the format of the links varies across the pages.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `curl`, `wget` or someting similar.

Here are some similar questions:

[Getting files, all at once, from a web page using curl](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100570/getting-files-all-at-once-from-a-web-page-using-curl)

[How to download all files (but no HTML) from a website using wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755229/how-to-download-all-files-but-no-html-from-a-website-using-wget)

[How do I use wget to download all links from my site and save to a text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116987/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-links-from-my-site-and-save-to-a-text-file)

So yo could do like this:

```
curl --recursive --level 2 http://123.4.5.6/3/4
```

or using short arguments

```
curl -r -l 2 http://123.4.5.6/3/4
```

Actually this doesn't make a click, but it does make a request and get its answer. The `-r` argument means it will recursively request all links and the links found in the answers of this links and so on. The `-l` argument specifies the recursion maximum depth level. So change the number 2 according to your needs.

Yo can check the man page to get more info, just type `man curl` in your terminal. Jump to the recursion info typing `/Recursive Retrieval Options`.